# Search records from database and adding them to list

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

i am a beginner developr in ruby on rails.
What i want to do is:

1. to create an input search to search products.
2. Then, i click a submit button, this product will be dispalyed in a list below.
3. I search another product and it will be added to my list.
4. Finally, i will have a list of searched products.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
var foodList = [];

function addToFood () {
    var addFood = document.getElementById('addFood').value;
    var addQuantity = document.getElementById('addFood').value;

    foodList.push(addFood + "  " + addQuantity );

    
    for (i = 0; i < foodList.length; i++) {
        var newFood = "<a href='#' onClick='removeRecord(" + i + ");'>X</a> " + foodList[i] + " <br>";
    };
    document.getElementById('foods').innerHTML += newFood;

    document.getElementById('addQuantity').value = '';
    document.getElementById('addFood').value = '';

}


function removeRecord (i) {
    foodList.splice(i, 1);
    var newFood = "";
    // re-display the records from foodList the same way we did it in addToFood()
    for (var i = 0; i < foodList.length; i++) {
        newFood += "<a href='#' onClick='removeRecord(" + i + ");'>X</a> " + foodList[i] + " <br>";
    };
    document.getElementById('foods').innerHTML = newFood;
}

</script>
```

```html
<%= form_tag akala_health_path, :method => 'get', :id => "products_search" do %>
  <p>
    Product name
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] , :id => "addFood"%></br>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
  
<% end %>
  
<table id="products">
  <tr>
    <th>Product name</th>
    <th>Product code</th>
    <th>Product quantity</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <% if @products.count == 0 %>
  <% else %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td id="addFood"><%= product.product_name %></td>   
        <td id="addFood"><%= product.product_code %></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""  /></br></td> 
        <td><input type="submit" value="Ajouter" onClick="addToFood();"> </td>
      </tr> 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @products%>
<!-- The list of food is displayed in the following div -->    
<div id="foods"></div>
```

How can i do this ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make ajax requests to get products from the app server. If you are not familiar with ajax/rails, a good place to start is on rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html